# Android keyboard breaks design

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I design html page with an interface using css for android devices. It looks great:

[image]

The problem is that when I click on an area that opens the keyboard the resolution changes, breaking the all design.

[image]

In ios devices the keyboad floats over the browser and this issue dosen't happens.

Is there some way to avoid this or some fix to apply?

Comment: I haven't messed with webviews before really, but I know that this is the standard funcitonality of adjustResize declared in your manifest for your activity. Are you doing that by chance? Either way, maybe try setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for your activity in your manifest.

Comment: can you create a JSfiddle with your code?